# TypeError: 'undefined is not a function when' installing new keystonejs application

Tags: keystonejs

I am following this steps :
http://keystonejs.com/getting-started/

```
nodejs - v0.12.7 
mongod - db version v3.2.0
```

but I am getting the error below

```
 } if (userModelPath.includes('-')) { ;
                     ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at eval (eval at template (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-keystone/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:6306:22), <anonymous>:77:22)
    at KeystoneGenerator.underscore [as _engine] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-keystone/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/util/engines.js:31:45)
    at KeystoneGenerator.engine (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-keystone/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/actions.js:314:10)
    at KeystoneGenerator.template (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-keystone/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/actions/actions.js:289:15)
    at KeystoneGenerator.project (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-keystone/app/index.js:320:7)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-keystone/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:395:14
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
Sergius-MacBook-Pro:keystoneadmin sergiu$
```

Comment: Are you getting this error when trying to use the Yeoman generator to create Keystone from the beginning?

Comment: Same error as @Webdesign7 London. Has anyone fixed it? Or at least a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your version of Node.js

String.prototype.includes() was most likely String.prototype.contains() in your version of Node.js